# TextWatcher из RecyclerView влияет на TextWatcher во Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-edittext

У меня на одном экране выведен EditText из фрагмента и для него добавлен TextWatcher. На этом же экране выведен RecyclerView, в котором тоже содержатся EditText. В адаптере для них создан свой TextWatcher. Это привело к тому, что TextWatcher из адаптера выполняет TextWatcher который во фрагменте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким образом: если фокус на EditText, который RecyclerView, TextWatcher находящийся во фрагмете отключается. Если фокус попадает на EditText во фрагменте, TextWatcher фрагмента снова активен.